# Как реализовать метод?

Tags: java

У меня есть HashSet<Region>. Хочу определить принадлежит ли текущий регион тем, что лежит в сете. Делаю это вот так:

```
    HashSet<Region> reg = new HashSet<Region>();
    Region r1 = new Region();
    r1.setValue(Region.Regions.region1);
    Region r2 = new Region();
    r2.setValue(Region.Regions.region2);
    reg.add(r1);
    reg.add(r2);

    Region r = new Region();
    r.setValue(Region.Regions.region1);

    out.println(reg.contains(r));
```

Почему то выдает false. В чем проблема?

Вот как реализован класс Region

```
public class Region {

private Regions value;

public Regions getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Regions value) {
    this.value = value;
}

static enum Regions {
    region1("region - 1"),
    region2("region - 2"),
    region3("region - 3"),
    region4("region - 4");

    private String value;

    Regions(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У класса Region необходимо переопределить метод equals(), который наследуется от класса Object. Именно он используется для сравнения объектов при поиске.

Внутри него объекты должны сравниваться по значениям полей или каким-либо другим свойствам (в вашем случае, достаточно сравнить value, я думаю)

Comment: и hashCode() для полноты картины =)

Comment: да и стоит добавить, что Set - по определения не может содержать дублей

Comment: в данном случаи hashCode более чем обязателен

Comment: а как переопределить метод equals()?

Comment: если пишите в эклипсе можно выбрать пункт контекстного меню source -> override/implements (как то так пункт меню) и выбрать нужный метод класса Object или же ручками, если же вы про саму реализацию то проверить что они одного типа, а дальше по хэшкоду (который тоже лучше бы переопределить)

Comment: @rasmisha а можете на коде показать, а то что-то не понимаю...

Comment: вам к Джошуа Блоху (http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2127002). Полистайте там где-то в первых главах по-моему это есть

Comment: переопределил equals(), вот только результат тот же..